# Inserting value from array into special output

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have this special output:

```
dAmn_Raw('send chat:Sandbox\n\nmsg main\n\nthismessage');
```

I have a variable: `myvariable` that equals a random value from an array I made.

I'd like this random value to show up in chat through this output, but I can't include
it in the output line of code. How would I got about writing something that replaces a default message (in this case "`thismessage`") with whatever value `myVariable`holds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand why you can't just:

```
dAmn_Raw('send chat:Sandbox\n\nmsg main\n\n' + myVariable);
```